# too much space between lines in a table

Tags: html, css

i have this code on [this jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/9EL5f/) and i have problems with text align: as you can see there is a lot of space between the lines!

Why?

```
table {
    width: 700px;
    margin-left: 130px;
    margin-right: 130px;
}
tr {
    width: 500px;
    float: center;
}
td {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: auto 30px auto 30px;
    font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    color:red;
    line-height: -3;
    text-align: right;
}
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by between the lines. You have a lot of space in between each image + text, are you trying to close the gap of each set or just the text itself?

Comment: hmm you have 30px padding on the top and on the bottom for each cell. Have you tried to change this to a lower value?

Comment: Not necessarily related to your problem, but note that your [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) value won't take effect, because `auto` is not a valid padding value (only "lengths" and percentages are). Also, a [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) of `-3` is also invalid (it has to be positive).

Answer (score 3):

It is because the images in your table are pushing all content down below them after that content exceeds 300px in width. To stop it, you could set img as so in your css.

```
img{
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9EL5f/1/

**EDIT: If you want your text to be in the middle then you should perhaps go for a pure css styled approach and don't use HTML tables at all.**

e.g

```
<div id="col1"><img ... /><span>Text goes here</span></div>
```

You would fill this div with however many rows of images and text you wanted and then style them in your css. You would then repeat it for a second column. Your css for the column alone would look something like:

```
#col1{
    width:500px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px; //add space between this column and the next one.
    }
```

Comment: No! Cause i want that image and tex are aligned vertically in the middle together

Comment: And how can i make a table just with css? o.ò

Comment: You could make two <div> elements and use CSS to style them as columns (set the width etc) and style the images and text within each column as you see fit.

Comment: You Fiddle is not an answer to the question and the to display the images as 'block' is far from being the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the images are aligned vertically (valign="middle"). Css renders it as if it should be situated on the line itself, meaning the line-height will be stretched. Just delete it and it should be fine

Comment: i need the vertical align in the middle o.ò

Answer (score 2):

Set image display to block. Like display:block

img{ display:block;}

Answer (score 2):

try this out img{ display:block;}

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of errors in both your HTML markup as well as in your CSS code (always [**validate**](http://validator.w3.org/) your HTML + CSS code).

I have corrected all your faults in the jsFiddle.

The "key" to your problem is that you have to set `vertical-align: middle` on the `img`

Here is the working example: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9EL5f/8/)

PS: This fails, if the TD's aren't wide enough so that the text wraps to a second line. In this case it would be better to define the images as `background-image` and just add a `padding-left: 80px` to the `td`.

Comment: This is just a hackish approach that still encourages the use of tables for layout (also, why have you added a border?). Ideally the author should be re-implementing this using CSS for her styling purposes and enforcing a separation of concerns between her HTML and CSS.

Comment: @BenM: Ah, and your proposed solution (see jsFiddle) is not!? Beside the fact that table elements should only be used for tabular data, the questioner should see how table "works". Which he cannot by your proposal (you also had left the errors in the CSS). And I added the borders just for demonstration purposes to easily see the dimensions of the TD's. But thanks for downvoting anyway ...!

Comment: No mine is not hackish. I specified a behavior that is reliable and consistent. A behaviour that will not be affected by different widths for example. I then advised that if they wanted to achieve the centering effect correctly, to use pure CSS styling and forget using tables.